# psycopg2 cannot connect to docker image

Tags: python, django, docker, psycopg2

I've started my docker image as follows:

```
docker run --name fnf-postgis -e POSTGRES_DB=fnf -e POSTGRES_USER=fnfuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=fnf2pwd -p5432:5432 -d mdillon/postgis:11
```

and i've set up my django db config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'fnf',
        'USER': 'fnfuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'fnf2pwd',
        'host': '',
        'port': 5432,
```

However, running `makemigrations` give this error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file
>   or directory  Is the server running locally and accepting     connections
>   on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

but I can successfully connect to the container from pycharm

[image]

Comment: please show your `pycharm` database conecction settings.

Comment: @BearBrown done

Comment: try to change the 'host' to 'localhost' instead of empty string

Comment: I am not sure but don't you have to specify localhost in your 'host' ?

Comment: I've tried, localhost and 0.0.0.0, but nothing works.

Comment: after running `docker run....`, whats the result of `docker ps` ? @Tjorriemorrie

Answer (score 7):

As per psycopg2's [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html?highlight=operationalerror#psycopg2.connect). If the host value is empty then by default it will look for the Unix Socket file of Postgres.

And in your error message, it is mentioned that it is looking for the socket file (**.s.PGSQL.5432**) under the `tmp` directory.

If you are running `postgres` as a seperate container, then you can find out this socket file under `/var/run/postgresql` directory in your container.

You can mount this folder to your host like below:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -v /home/username/socket_dir:/var/run/postgresql -d postgres
```

then you can update your **DATABASE** object like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'fnf',
        'USER': 'fnfuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'fnf2pwd',
        'host': '/home/username/socket_dir/',
        'port': 5432,
```

Now the connection should be established.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between your Pycharm and your Django settings.

Pycharm explicitely connects to `localhost` when Django setting is trying to connect to `''`.

Simply putting `'localhost'` as your `HOST` Django setting should work.

**Please note that the correct setting names are uppercase `HOST` and `PORT`, not lower case `host` and `port`.**

Answer (score 1):

You should provide name of postgresql docker container as value to `host` key:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'fnf',
        'USER': 'fnfuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'fnf2pwd',
        'HOST': 'fnf-postgis', # Name of postgres docker container
        'PORT': 5432, # Its exposed port
    }
}
```